# Solving recurrence relations of n rabbits on island

Tags: recurrence-relations, relations

Okay so one pair of rabbits is left in an island. 
After 1 month it produces 2 pairs of rabbits, and 2 months or older they produce 6 every month.
I came up with the recurrence relation

$ A_{n} = 2(A_{n-1} - A_{n-2}) + 6A_{n-2} + A_{n-1} $

For n >= 2,
Which finds the total pairs of rabbits on the island after n months (rabbits never die)
My problem is that the next problem says to solve it in terms of just n and I have been breaking my head but can't make any progress.... for example the equation have a format of just n:

$ A_{n} = 2n^n + 6n^n + n$

How does one solve this problem?

Comment: Look for solutions of the form $A_n = r^n$.  If you plug in this expression to your recurrence relation, you will get an algebraic equation for $r$.  The roots of that equation generate the possible sequences that can be combined linearly to meet your initial conditions (rabbits "left in an island").

Comment: When substituting I ended up with 
$ 4r^{n-2} +3r^{n-1} - r^n = 0 $
would the next step be logarithmic differentiation to bring down the powers? Thanks for the help, hardmath

Comment: The next step is factoring out $r^{n-2}$

Comment: $ r^{n-2} * (4 + 3r - r^2) $ 
I solved for r = 0,-1,4 and tried using the format our professor gave us to solve for $ a_n = C_{1}(4)^n + C_{2}(-1)^n $ but that didn't work when I solved for it. Sorry for the trouble but could you help me once more?

Comment: First I would like you to think about whether your steps so far are consistent.  As you describe it, "rabbits never die".  Therefore the population of rabbits should be strictly increasing as (pairs of) rabbits are born.  None of your solutions $r=0,1,-4$ match that behavior.

Comment: My bad, it was 0, -1, 4. 

$ r^{n-2} * (4 + 3r - r^2) = 0 $ is what I had so far, 

$ r^{n-2} = 0 $, r = 0

$ (4 + 3r - r^2) = 0 $ r = 4, -1

Comment: Good, so let's work out the first couple of terms in the sequence and fit the combination of $4^n$ and $(-1)^n$ to those initial conditions.

Comment: Alright so I know $A_2 = 13 $ and $ A_3 = 51 $, if i try substituting $A_2$ on the above format I get $ 13 = C_{1}(16) + C_{2}(1) $ if $ C_1  = 1 $ then $ C_2 = -3 $ this however doesn't match with $ A_3 $, which equals 61 instead of 51

Comment: But $C_1$ is not $1$.  You have to solve a pair of linear equations for $C_1,C_2$.  In this case your coefficients are fractions.

Comment: Okay, so $13 = C_1 (16) + C_2 (1) $ I solved for $C_2$ resulting in $C_2 = 13/(C_1)(16). $ Plugged in $C_2$ in the $A_3$ formula for $51 = (C_1)(256) + (13/(16)(C_1)) $ I move 51, let's say $ C_2 = x $. Multiply everything by x to get $ 256x^2 - 51x - 13/16 = 0 $

Comment: You need to set up two linear equations for the two unknowns.  If you like, you can use the terms $A_2 = 13$ and $A_3 = 51$, but you will not get a quadratic equation to solve.  It was easier for me to use $A_0 = 1$ and $A_1 = 3$, but the coefficients $C_1,C_2$ you will find are the same.

Comment: The issue is that i don't think the first recurrence equation works for $A_0 & A_1 $ so that's why I used 2 and 3, and well I thought what I was doing was linear equations,  I redid it and found out it's actually 
$ 51 = (C_1)(256) - (13/(16)(C_1)) $
wouldn't setting it to 0 and using the quadratic formula help?
Again, thanks again for your time&patience, hardmath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recurrence relationship was found correctly:

$$ A_n = 2(A_{n-1} - A_{n-2}) + 6A_{n-2} + A_{n-1} $$

Collecting like-terms and setting $A_n = r^n$ produces the characteristic equation:

$$ r^2 - 3r - 4 = 0 $$

whose (nonzero) roots are $r = 4,-1$.

We can set up a system of two linear equations to find coefficients of the geometric sequences that match our initial conditions, $A_n = (4^n)C_1 + (-1)^n C_2$.

The OP expressed doubt that the initial conditions $A_0 = 1,A_1 = 3$ would provide a correct solution, so let's use the terms $A_2 = 13,A_3 = 51$:

$$ (4^2)C_1 + (-1)^2 C_2 = 13 $$
$$ (4^3)C_1 + (-1)^3 C_2 = 51 $$

Subtracting $4$ times the first equation from the second equation gives:

$$ (-1 - 4)C_2 = 51 - 52 = -1 $$

Therefore $C_2 = 1/5$, and substituting this into either of the two original equations allows us to solve for $C_1 = 4/5$.

Note that the solution is valid for both of the terms $A_0,A_1$ as well:

$$ (4^0)C_1 + (-1)^0 C_2 = 1 = A_0 $$
$$ (4^1)C_1 + (-1)^1 C_2 = 3 = A_1 $$

So we could have gotten the same coefficients using these smaller terms.

Comment: I see it now, like you said, there really wasn't a need for the quadratic formula... thank you so much!

Comment: @Roger: Right, you divided when you should have subtracted, $C_2 = 13 - 16C_1$.  You can "eliminate" $C_2$ by substituting in the second equation and getting an equation for $C_1$ alone.  Left as an exercise for the reader!